# Are there any shower facilities at Amsterdam Centraal station?

Tags: trains, train-stations, night-transport

I will travel to Amsterdam for a conference, and plan to arrive by sleeper train.

Are there any showers available at Amsterdam Centraal station?
I would like to freshen up after the night train ride, then join the conference straight away.

Last year, on the same route (Amsterdam-Basel), the consist had sleeping cars without showers, unlike on other Nightjet routes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there aren't

The toilets are now run privately by Sanifair ([NS Facilities page](https://www.ns.nl/stationsinformatie/asd/amsterdam-centraal))

[Sanifair map](https://www.sanifair.com/location-search) mentions that no showers are available in their locations in the Netherlands

A [forum post](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g188590-i60-k12970862-Shower_Room_Amsterdam_Central-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html) mentions that there used to be such showers but not anymore